# Sitemap in Bing pending for two weeks

Tags: seo, sitemap, bing

I built a new website a month ago.  Two weeks ago I had submitted the sitemap in  Bing search console.

At this point, it is still in pending status. What should I do to get Bing moving on it?

Answer (score 1):

Use one of these links.

[http://www.bing.com/webmaster/ping.aspx?siteMap={full url to your sitemap)](http://www.bing.com/webmaster/ping.aspx?siteMap=%7Bfull%20url%20to%20your%20sitemap))
or
[http://www.bing.com/ping?sitemap=[your sitemap web address]](http://www.bing.com/ping?sitemap=[your%20sitemap%20web%20address])

This will give Big a nudge on your sitemap and there is a high chance it will get going within a few hours or a couple of days. I worked well for me